# Is PAD(EXP) = P?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, complexity-classes, polynomial-time

Can I say that all languages in the class $\textbf{P}$ are just a padded version of some other problem in $\textbf{EXP}$?

I am familiar with the padding argument, which states that if $\textbf{P} = \textbf{NP}$, then $\textbf{EXP} = \textbf{NEXP}$. I describe the languages obtained by padding an exponential-time problem into a polynomial-time problem as $\text{Pad}(\textbf{EXP})$. Since my padding is exponentially sized, it is clear to see $\text{Pad}(\textbf{EXP}) \subset \textbf{P}$. Now, my question would be if this is a strict subset.

**Edit:** I believe that it is not a strict subset, as the size of padding is $2^{|x|^c}$ for some constant $c$. This allows me to control the amount of padding I do, although I am unclear on whether I can have no padding at all since setting $c = 0$ still has $2$ padding.

**Edit 2:** If I am allowed to control the amount of padding, then I can construct languages in $\text{Pad}(\textbf{EXP})$ that don't even belong to $\textbf{P}$. This breaks my previous argument.